# Missing Visual Studio 2010 Sample Macros

Tags: macros

In my Visual Studio 2010 Macro Explorer I have the "Samples" folder but it is empty.

Everything I read seems to indicate that these should have been installed automatically.

I ran Setup again to see if it was a feature that I missed but there was no option.

Any ideas how I can get the sample macros?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I resolved it.  I went to another computer that had Visual Studio 2010 installed and copied the file Samples.vsmacros from that PC to mine.  So I have the Sample macros now.

Thanks.